# What operation is denoted by this subscript notation?

Tags: notation, number-systems

What operation is denoted here?

$$11_3$$

I believe the answer to this is 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Base*, or *radix*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)

$11_3$ is the number $4$ written in base $3$:
$$
11_3 = 1\cdot 3^1+1\cdot 3^0 = 3+1=4
$$
*A small nitpick:* it is not technically an *operation*, but a notation.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an operation - it's a sign for what base the number is expressed in.

$11_3=4_{10}$.